# How can I update a User Record from a custom AuthProviderPlugin's getUserInfo() method?

Tags: apex, integration, rest, oauth2, namedcredentials

I am trying to integrate Salesforce with [Jira using a Named Credential and oAuth 2.0](https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/platform/oauth-2-authorization-code-grants-3lo-for-apps/). The Named Credential requires a Custom Auth. Provider which requires an `AuthProviderPluginClass`.  The authentication and authorization are working fine, and everything for the named credential appears to be stored as expected.

The hiccup here is that making requests with oAuth requires a `cloudId` (issued by Jira)  to be passed as part of the request URL.  I can get the `cloudId` for the authenticating user and use that to make additional requests while I'm still in the `AuthProviderPluginClass`, but any attempt to persist the `cloudId` has been met with failure. I can see the `cloudId` and UserId in the debug logs, but no matter what I do I can't seem to save the `cloudId` seemingly because the `AuthProviderPluginClass` is 'swallowing' everything.

I have tried:

1. Updating the User record using DML.  I can see the `DML_OPERATION` line in the debug log, but the field on the User remains blank.
2. Updating the User record using DML in a `@future` method.  In this case I can see the `METHOD_ENTRY` line in the debug log, but no `futureHandler` log ever gets created and the field on the User remains blank.
3. Adding a `cloudId` field to the Custom Metadata driving the Auth. Provider, using Apex's `Metadata` class to deploy the `cloudId` when I retrieve it from Jira.  This works when I run the code in the Execute Anonymous window, and once again I can see the `METHOD_ENTRY` debug line when I call the code from within the `AuthProviderPluginClass`, but no deployment job gets created when the method is called this way.

I am aware that Jira supports basic authentication with UserName and Password, but since this is being deprecated and the integration I'm building is for an AppExchange package, I'd really like to get the oAuth flow working.  Any tips on how to persist the `cloudId` would be appreciated.

Comment: That is odd.  Can you post some of the code you've tried?  Curious to get a look at this.